# Check if sqlite3 database null

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am building a ios app in which sqlite file is initiated once and is used in all sqlite transaction; it is done to save performance.
It is defined as:

```
static sqlite3 *dbName = nil;
```

In the function, i initialize database as:

```
-(int)initialize:(NSString *)dbPath{
    if (sqlite3_open_v2(dbPath, &dbName, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        //some codes
    }
}
```

After some transaction, i found sqlite3 instance is NULL and app crashed. I am wondering if there is a way to check if sqlite3 instance is deallocated or not.

Comment: static? Shouldn't you rather use singleton pattern class i.e. `DatabaseManager` and keep the instance in that class so that it ensures that it retains its state and can be access throughout the app?

Comment: i will do as you said. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can see two potential issues:

1. You are opening the database multiple times and eventually (I cannot say when) it's giving up and setting the handle to `NULL`.  This is because you are not guarding against opening it multiple times.
2. Your code shows `sqlite3_open_v2(dbPath, &dbPath, ...` which cannot be right.  The name `dbName` is not well chosen, either.

This should fix most of that:

```
-(int)initialize:(NSString *)dbPath{
    if (dbName == NULL) {
        if (sqlite3_open_v2(dbPath, &dbName, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            //some codes
        }
    }
}
```

You are also better off using the singleton pattern, rather than `static`, as it's much cleaner.